# Ubuntu 22.04 freezes

Tags: drivers, graphics, freeze, 22.04

I just started using Ubuntu 22.04 and it keeps freezing a couple seconds after starting forcing me to restart the laptop with the power button. I'm guessing it has something to do with the graphics card, but I don't really know. I'm currently using a HP ENVY - 13-ah0006no laptop with an Intel UHD Graphics 620 GPU. Another thing that I'm not sure if it's related is when I boot I get `ACPI BIOS Error (bug): could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC ]`

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I currently have 8 GB

Comment: That should be good enough. Something else is causing the issue. Let's wait for someone with more technical skills to address the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. It freezes for about 10-30 sec, and it comes back. Don't why either.